Searching for alternative of doing maths with pen and paper
I am curious about is there software alternative of doing math stuff instead of writing equations in pen and paper, I am in computer science and occasionally required to read proofs specially in Linear algebra, probability and machine learning. I thought that there should be a system that verifies that what I am writing is valid math or nor, checking correctness of things, and how mathematical constructs are being build, what is dependency of a specific math equation.
I know that chat assistants like chat GPT could help. But I want complete alternative of pen and paper. I am also curious about a system in which I can write research papers in which all the statements are proven to be true.
I get to know about proof assistant lib like lean and coq. Are these lib worth learning for my situation. I am also thinking that some I-Pad/tablet kind of interface could be build on top of these languages could be good project. I think that at current time math should not be written and read in ancient pen and paper way.
I hope you understand my thinking.
Thank you for your future suggestions.

Everyone I know that works with computerized proof assistants still uses pen and paper (or a whiteboard) at least every once in a while. Apart from that I'm not sure what you are looking for--computer proof assistants require you to be precise enough with your language that it does not really look like pen-and-paper proofs.

Unless you need to make sure that all of the math your're working on is guaranteed to be correct (for instance because security or system-critical components depend on it), I would say it's not worth learning proof assistants. The initial investment is fairly high and it's not really going to help you process more math. Rather on the contrary, your math will get slower (but "correcter").

But come back in 15 years to greet our AI-driven proof lords.

What is your goal? If you are shaky with mathematical reasoning / not so sure your proofs make sense, it will certainly not be easier to formalize all your proofs in a proof assistant, in the same way that you wouldn't take on a challenge of running long distances with a heavy weight in a backpack if you're not a good runner to start with. On the other hand, it is possible that learning the basics of a proof assistant (on elementary things, not your actual work) could help you become more fluent in mathematical reasoning.

Also, since you mention iPad/tablet interfaces, I will say that you might have to lower your expectations quite a lot for the time being. At the moment, proof assistants are nowhere near the level where accessibility on tablets would be the main hurdle to use them.

TL;DR: The system you are looking for doesn't exist, and if it did it probably wouldn't help at your level, but keep the dream alive.
Nothing beats pen and paper (except maybe pencil and paper, or chalk and blackboard) with working through difficult math.
What pen and paper gives you is the totally unencumbered experience where you can link the vague concepts in your mind to physical paper.  You can doodle, make up you own notation, write ideas in your favorite language (both natural like English and symbolic).
There is certainly an advantage of adding technology to the mathematical discovery process, but it comes at a cost, especially when first adopting it.
The main cost is that your attention on the mathematics is broken up by having to think about the implementation details of the technology.
For example, if you use a tablet and stylus instead of pen and paper, it will have some advantages like everything being in one place and an easy ability to send your writings to others.  But you will also have to occasionally fight with the technology.
A larger commitment is learning $LaTeX$.  It is necessary for any mathematician and most computer scientists, but it has a large cost, especially in the first few years of learning it.  You can't doodle on $LaTeX$ (at least without a lot of frustration learning TikZ, etc.).  I've heard professors express worry when a student's homework is turned in via LaTeX, since the prettiness of the work overshadows the mistakes in reasoning.  And my own experience is that for every 10 minutes I spend thinking about math in $LaTeX$, I spend 20 minutes looking up stuff and fighting compilation errors.  (Try writing the DFT matrix in LaTeX verse on paper?)  I've never found value in rewriting my course notes in LaTeX.  (I instead do the simplest thing possible, just doodling and writing on paper until I understand a concept/proof and then move to the next idea, not focusing on having anything resembling a pretty output.)  Of course, the value of using $LaTeX$ as a communication tool is not to be underestimated, and a proficient mathematician might indeed start writing notes or working out some concepts on $LaTeX$ (or psuedo-LaTeX, or markdown with LaTeX like this website uses).
Search engines are still currently the best tool for looking up mathematics
Assume that you are confused about a topic, such as if every injective linear map is also subjective, even if I'm talking about an infinite dimensional vector space like the vector space polynomials.  This may change soon, but currently, search engines like Google are still one of the best places to find out information like this.  You will be able to look at Wikipedia (not always correct, but often is), course notes, books, and Q&A sites like Math Stack Exchange or MathOverflow (the latter for professional mathematics).  If you can't find the answer (and you have already thought about it for yourself), then asking a human on Math Stack Exchange is probably a good bet.
Now, I think chat-based AI like ChatGPT and Google's AI is starting to make a dent here.  You really shouldn't trust what they say.  (Think of them like a knowledgable, but cocky and overconfident peer.  Double-check and triple-check everything they say.)  But considering the recent merger of chat-AI and search spaces, with ChatGPT now returning references and Google returning AI summaries, you can use the AI-suggested links to quickly find your answer, and it is possible the flexibility of the AI could help with even more esoteric math questions.
Symbolic tool are good for calculations
Depending on the sort of math you do, you may run into a number of calculations.  Some are as simple as multiplying some numbers where a calculator would work.  Others involve solving integrals or complicated simplifications where a CAS like Wolfram Alpha would help.  For verifying some identities like $e^x \geq 1+x$, a first approximation would be just to plot both sides of the inequality (although a mathematician would cringe if that was your ultimate proof of that fact).  And last, lots of mathematicians write code (say in Python) to check a conjecture for a finite number of cases, or to plot patterns.
Proof assistants have value, but they aren't magic tools
Proof assistants have two main uses currently.  They are good for formalizing mathematics as an end in itself.  They are good for checking minute details in complicated proofs which are of particular importance.  For the second, if you imagine verifying the correctness of a specific piece of Rust code.  It might have an off-by-one error.  This error doesn't really affect the mathematical ideas in the algorithm.  It is a simple mistake.  However, that small error could cause the program to crash (or an airplane to crash) or to expose private customer data.  That is when checking the details is particularly important.  Less common, there are some math proofs that are so technical, but also quite important that it is worth spending time checking them.
Currently, they really aren't practical tools for understanding a paper or for  working through your own new proof.  The amount of time needed to learn the system and check your work would outweigh the added verification.  Further, proof assistant users often still work things out with pen and paper first, then sometimes move to LaTeX, and finally Lean or Coq.  It is just so easy to get lost in the details when doing things on a computer.
While you might think about checking some long-calculation on a proof assistant, but currently the amount of work needed to put it into the right syntax and then just doing simple algebraic manipulations to check your computations would probably not make them worth it for most applications.
Keep dreaming!
As these technologies get better, maybe there will be a point where one could easily use proof-assistant-like technology to check mathematical ideas or calculations.  I could imagine a chat interface where you say, "Is it true that every injective linear from the polynomials to the polynomials is also subjective?"  It would translate the question into Lean, and come up with a counterexample, which it also checks in Lean.  Or where you put in a long $LaTeX$ calculation involving various symbolic manipulations and identities and again the system translates this to Lean, fills in the details for each step of the calculation, and maybe even uses a CAS for some of the calculations.  This is certainly within the realm of possibility, and not far from the current technology, but it doesn't exist right now in practice.

Just as an aside, it is still rather niche, but some people do use proof assistants (potentially in combination with more traditional pen & paper or blackboard) as a part of their everyday research activity, rather than some sort of "afterthought". This is still far from common, but for some proof assistants beat pen & paper, now. Although of course there is still a lot of space for making the experience much smoother, for them and everyone else.

@MevenLennon-Bertrand what sort of research?  I imagine it is still quite niche and where the proof assistant closely matches a formal system that the researcher is interested in, like homotopy type theory?  Or where the proof is so technical or controversial it wouldn’t be believed otherwise.  But maybe I’m underestimating and there are more solid use cases.  (Maybe this should even be an answer.)

I'm mainly thinking about either homotopy type theory or PL theory, yes. So indeed places where people have a very good proficiency with the tool, and are working on topics for which they are well-suited. But for instance the recent work on busy beaver was as far as I understand also somewhat co-developed?
